# Chrome NativeHostClient installer on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have my Chrome extension which talks to a NativeHostClient. I want to create an installer to install my NativeHostClient (I just require a json file to move to NativeHost directory under Chrome folder).

I am fairly new to these installers. I tried few installer creators apps but all require admin privileges. Is there an example for installing a Chrome NativeHostClient through a installer for OS X?

Answer (score 0):

The **Packages** can create a pkg installer which install files in current user's home directory. [Here is the instruction described how to do it](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/Q&A_3.html).
Once you decide to install `native messaging host` in user directory, the `path` in native messaging host's manifest file must be absolute and point to right location. A solution is created a post install script to produce the json file, or copy a template json file then modify it using `sed` command.